# Sharepoint image referencing

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint

I can't seem to find the correct encapsulating or prefix syntax for referencing an image located in xxxx site collection.

Right now I have three variations of one image that will be applied to the footer.  And these variants are selected based on the site collection, so I can't directly set the image to the masterpage (Unless I want to make three masterpages, which is just overkill for a single image).

I have tried going about this using Javascript to set the source of an img element and CSS to set the url of a container element's background-image.  Both are failing me.

In Javascript, I have tried setting the src attribute of my element to:

`"<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property='SiteUrl' runat='server' />/_catalogs/masterpage/Images/myimage.gif;"`

`"<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Images/myimage.gif %>";`

`"~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Images/myimage.gif";`

and repeated the same with CSS for background-image property to a div element.  But all I ever get is errors or it doesn't translate the sharepoint code.

Does anyone have any idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these URLs for reference - 
http://www.vrdmn.com/2011/08/javascript-lmenubaseurl-varaible-for.html
http://johnliu.net/blog/2012/2/3/sharepoint-javascript-current-page-context-info.html
http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2013/01/getting-web-url-with-sharepoint-2010.html

and try the below method to get the URL.

```
<%script type="text/javascript">

var url = "<%= SPContext.Current.Site.Url %>";

</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're method may not work for me if that blog is to be believed.  But I will try it later.  And thanks for the reference sites.

Comment: Tried your method and still no luck.  Seems the only way for me to get an image that any site collection can use is to place it inside the server HIVE (/layouts/15/).

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is this image stored?  Is it in the default "Images" library of a publishing site?  If so, you've got the wrong path.  It would be "/PublishingImages/myimage.gif".

Comment: It is stored exactly where I stated in my original post.  The absolute path(s) would be something like:

www.SPwebsite.com/sites/mysite/_catalogs/masterpage/Images/myimage.gif

Comment: have you checked in the image, and what excatly is the error you are geeting

Comment: The image is loaded in the correct directory.  I can see it and download it.  I don't remember what the errors were; the holidays have befuddled my brain.  But more often than not, a javascript error woould mention invalid property